# Why are the insert options grayed out when I open a PDF?

Tags: preview

in Preview, I opened up a PDF containing an image. I need to combine it with a portion of another such PDF. When opened, it was locked, so I duplicated it. However, the insert sub-options remain grayed out, so I can't add a page. Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files I was opening were JPG, not PDF, and even though my intention was to create PDF files, apparently I'd need to first save one as a PDF and then open it to insert another page.